# Retrieve Opportunity Data in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have created an dynamic email template using AMP Script so that i can send emails to all records which are present in my salesforce report.

**AMP Script:**

```
%%[
    Var @fname,@AccountName,@PictureDay,@AccountPhone,@BookingOwner,@BookingOwnerEmail
    Set @fname=FirstName
    Set @AccountName=AccountName
    Set @PictureDay=PictureDay
    Set @AccountPhone=Account:Phone
    Set @BookingOwner=BookingOwner
    Set @BookingOwnerEmai=BookingOwnerEmail
]%%

Dear %%=v(@fname)=%%,

We are looking forward to taking photographs at %%=v(@AccountName)=%% on %%=v(@PictureDay)=%%. The phone number we have on file for you is %%=v(@AccountPhone)=%%.

Your Account Manager is %%=v(@BookingOwner)=%% and you can reach them at %%=v(@BookingOwnerEmail)=%%
```

**Notes:**

1. I don't want to import data using Salesforce Data Extension.
2. I have Opportunity columns in my report so i am unable to fetch from normal Data Extension (They can fetch only Contact,Lead & Opportunity columns)
3. Trying to use AMP Script for Dynamic Email Content.
4. Tried using RetrieveSalesforceObject function but no luck.

Comment: What error are you getting with the RetrieveSalesforceObject?

Comment: Do you mind importing the Opportunity object with an import job in Automation Studio?

Comment: Does RetrieveSalesforceObject will work dynamically with records present in Salesforce Report? And also how to retrieve custom field on Opportunity ? How can we import the Opportunity object in Automation Studio?